# Calculating months elapsed since a given date

Tags: java, android, datetime

I am using traceview and DDMS to analyse my operation.  The following is my traceview as displayed in DDMS:

[image]

According to the above, the `LoaderClass.months()` function takes about 51% of the CPU time and 798.80 System time.  I have reproduced this function below:

```
public int months(String date) {

        SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date d1 = null;
        try {
            d1 = f.parse(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Date d2 = new Date();  
        Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        c1.setTime(d1);
        Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        c2.setTime(d2);
        int diff = 0;
        if (c2.after(c1)) {
            while (c2.after(c1)) {
                c1.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
                if (c2.after(c1)) {
                    diff++;
                }
            }
        } else if (c2.before(c1)) {
            while (c2.before(c1)) {
                c1.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
                if (c1.before(c2)) {
                    diff--;
                }
            }
        }
        return diff;
    }
```

Below is a more detailed view of the method as on DDMS:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel for what Joda time has already written for you:

```
int monthsBetween = Months.monthsBetween(new LocalDate(date1), new LocalDate()).getMonths();
```

From the `localDate` doc:

1. You can pass a string in the constructor. (you could test that)
2. Empty constructor is current time.

Comment: I highly regret that I did not use Joda Time. Now I have advanced too much in the project and reverting back is not an option.

Comment: you don't have to revert, add the dependency and this will work, your date1 and date2 are normal `java.util.Date`

Comment: I will have to make changes in each of my function - to  map them to Joda time, that is time consuming. However I will for sure check it out right now.

Comment: Can I invite you to the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) to discuss furter?

Comment: Did it with JODA, performance optimized by at least 65 percent! Cheers mate!

Comment: @ByzantineFailure - Java8 now has a new Date-manipulation API which borrows a lot from JodaTime.... oh, Android. My bad.

Answer (score 8):

I don't like the naming style you're using. Single and double-letter identifiers are annoying.

**Use meaningful names!**

Isn't this:

> ```
> SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
> ```

More enjoyable to read like that?

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Also, it's not immediately apparent what the method does - `months` looks more like a variable name than a method, because it doesn't start with a verb.

A more meaningful name could perhaps be `getElapsedMonths`... and then the `xx2` variables could be named `xxPresent`, and `xx1` could be `xxSpecified`, so `getElapsedMonths` would calculate the number of months elapsed since a *specified* date.

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely consider your advise, but the problem here is not with the naming that slows down the function, but the call to add does. It would be a huge help if you have any hints on how to improve that as well.