# Comparing dates (without the time part) in Java

Tags: java, datetime

In my current project, I have to deal a lot with dates, especially checking if the date entered by user is today, or max one year from today etc. As I find the datetime API of Java7 (which I regrettably still have to use) pretty confusing, in order to keep my code clean and readable, I wrote the following method:

```
public static int compareDates(Date date1, Date date2) {
    SimpleDateFormat math = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd"); // I'm working with servlets, so keeping it thread-safe
    Long date1asLong = new Long(math.format(date1));
    Long date2asLong = new Long(math.format(date2));
    return date1asLong.compareTo(date2asLong);
}

// usage, e.g. to find if the date entered by user is greater than today
if (MyDateUtils.compareDates(dateFromUser, new Date()) > 0) {
    // do the work
} else {
    // scream
}
```

Anyway, I am not sure whether this approach has any serious drawbacks, so I am throwing it here for review. Looking forward to your comments.

Comment: please check also [this answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/59466/calculating-months-elapsed-since-a-given-date/59475#59475) (and comments below)

Comment: Have you looked at using the Joda Time library? http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

Comment: Do you have any libraries on the classpath? Apache Commons stuff?

Answer (score 8):

It's an interesting, simple approach.

But you don't need `new Long` objects. Better use primitive types instead.

In fact, as [@njzk2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/21160/njzk2) pointed out in a comment,
you don't need `long` at all, as dates in `yyyyMMdd` format are alphabetically sorted, you can use simple String comparison.

It's good you mention in comments that you create a `SimpleDateFormat` instance inside the method for thread safety.
Another [common solution in such situations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817856/when-and-how-should-i-use-a-threadlocal-variable) is to use a `ThreadLocal`.
You can wrap a `SimpleDateFormat` instance in a `ThreadLocal` so that all threads will have their own copy, eliminating thread safety issues.

Last but not least, "math" is a poor name for a date formatter object.

Putting my suggestions together:

```
private static final ThreadLocal<DateFormat> dateFormatThreadLocal = new ThreadLocal<DateFormat>() {
    @Override
    protected DateFormat initialValue() {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    }
};

public static int compareDates(Date date1, Date date2) {
    DateFormat dateFormat = dateFormatThreadLocal.get();
    return dateFormat.format(date1).compareTo(dateFormat.format(date2));
}
```

Comment: Bear in mind that the `TheadLocal` approach will leak memory if the application undeployed. A `private static final BlockingQueue` would be better...

Comment: you don't even need the long at all. this format sorts dates by alphabetical order.

Comment: also, what thread safety issue? I don't think a call to `format` needs to be thread safe.

Comment: Thanks @njzk2, good point about the alphabetic ordering, I incorporated that in my answer. As for thread safety, OP wrote that the class is used by a servlet, and may need to be invoked from multiple threads, so format need to be made thread safe.

Comment: @janos after taking a look at openjdk's implementation for `format`, it appears you are right! `format` does modify and depends on the internal state of the `SimpleDateFormat` object (namely it changes the date on a local `Calendar` object)

Answer (score 5):

You may simply *truncate* given date to days (ignoring time part), one possible way to do it:

```
date1.toInstant().truncate(ChronoUnit.DAYS).isAfter(date2.toInstant())
```

It's faster than performing that conversions and IMO easier to read because methods are self-descriptive (*truncated to days date is after...*). You may want to have an helper method for that:

```
public static boolean isAfterToday(Date date) {
    return date.toInstant(truncate(ChronoUnits.DAYS).isAfter(Instant.now());
}
```

Used like this:

```
if (MyDateUtils.isAfterToday(dateFromUser)) {
    // do the work
} else {
    // scream
}
```

Note that if you heavily use dates you may also want to use [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), things will be even simpler:

```
public static boolean isAfterToday(DateTime date) {
    return DateTimeComparator.getDateOnlyInstance().compare(date, DateTime.now()) > 0;
}
```

If you can't use `Instant` (and obviously you don't want to include Joda Time just for this) you should at least use `Calendar` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1908419/1207195), in short:

```
public static long getDatePart(Date date) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    return cal.getTimeInMillis();
}
```

Used as:

```
if (getDatePart(dateFromuser) > getDatePart(Date.now())) {
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Regrettably, there is no such thing as `toInstant()` in Java7, to wich I am restricted due to customer's environment. The use of JodaTime seems to be a good idea, although it is still a bit to chatty.

Comment: Then I'd go with linked approach using Calendar. It's faster and reusable (you may want to extract date part in some other circumstances).

Comment: Note that Instant.truncatedTo() will truncate using UTC offset.

Answer (score 3):

**Main remarks**

1. *Use the existing `Comparator` abstraction*

   If you're solving a problem for comparisons, make a `Comparator`. Instead of having a method that compares `Date` instances on some util class, have a method there that returns a `Comparator` instead. Or even, make a standalone `Comparator` class. In this case, don't forget to document that it's not consistent with `equals()`.
2. *Don't forget about time zones*

   If you want to do calendar operations on a `Date` (and yes comparing by day is just that), then make sure you think about time zones. As it is, your code just takes the server's default time zone (which may be fine for your use case). It's just better to make this explicit, which also makes this more reusable and easier to test.

   Why is `TimeZone` important for calendar operations? Well since a single `Date` instance can fall on different calendar days depending on the `TimeZone`. If you have users in different time zones, they'll expect their entered dates to be interpreted vs. the time zone they're in.
3. *Use the right tool for the job: `java.util.Calendar`*

   Using `SimpleDateFormat` is clever, but it's just not the tool for the job. Use `Calendar`. The `SimpleDateFormat` class will be making a `Calendar` under the hood anyway, it will just also have to figure out formating it, and then after all the formatting, you'll just convert it to a number, while `Calendar` already has the numbers you need to compare.

**Minor remarks**

1. *String is `Comparable` too*

   Your conversion from `String` to `Long` is unnecessary, you could have compared the Strings directly. The format you use yields `String`s that have the same ordering as the respective `Long` instances.
2. *Use primitives whenever possible*

   If you did want to use numbers then prefer primitives if possible. `Long.parseLong()` and `Long.compare()` could help you avoid the boxes.

**Example code**

```
public static Comparator<Date> byDayComparator(final TimeZone timeZone) {
    return new Comparator<Date>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Date date1, Date date2) {
            return truncateToDay(date1).compareTo(truncateToDay(date2));
        }

        private Date truncateToDay(Date date) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(timeZone);
            calendar.setTime(date);
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
            return calendar.getTime();
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This isn't as transparent as the calendar version, but you can easily do this by dividing the time value to get a number of days. E.g.
long one-day = 24*60*60*1000
int compare = Long.compare(d1.getTime()/oneDay,d2.getTime()/oneDay)

Comment: This will fail because of DST.